# MOSFET switch for inverter

Tags: mosfet, switches

I need to control my el wire from Arduino Lilypad. I am going to use MOSFET switch circuit. El wire is ran from 9V battery and inverter circuit. Inverter is using about 90mA current. Lilypad has 3.3V output, so I am connecting it to IRLZ44 MOSFET and as inverter has a transformer in it inside, I need a flyback diode, right?

[image]

Comment: Can you add some additional information like part number and data sheet for the module that you are attempting to drive with the IRLZ44 MOSFET?

Comment: Thats a chinese inverter, for which I cannot find appropriate schematic, all of them are different.

Comment: Then it is not possible to answer your question. That module could be anything from a marble, a switching circuit to a penny for all we know. Maybe you want to consider acquiring components and modules that real data sheets so that you know what you are working with.

Comment: Vgs should really be at least 4V to switch this FET on, not just 3V3. Flyback diode probably won't hurt anything but depending on what's in the module, may not be necessary. I'd use it.

Answer (score 0):

3.3v are too low to turn on MOSFET and you have to add a driver like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwumla.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>